# How can I get TypeScript to stop complaining about a React rendered value being turned into a Date object?

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma, radix-ui

Next.js, TypeScript, Prisma, Radix-UI project. So I have a loan object that looks something like this

```
{
    "id": 25,
    "borrowerName": "Test Borrower 1",
    "pipelineStage": "PROSPECT",
    "loanAmount": 500000,
    "transactionType": "PURCHASE",
    "referralSource": "Realtor Lenny",
    "borrowerEmail": "test1@gmail.com",
    "propertyAddress": "1234 Test Way",
    "borrowerPhone": "789-546-3142",
    "purchasePrice": 700000,
    "creditScore": 700,
    "createdAt": "2024-03-15T21:46:18.347Z",
    "updatedAt": "2024-03-15T21:46:18.347Z"
}
```

I'm trying to build a "view single loan" page. I'm using Prisma, so createdAt and updatedAt are by default strings. Here's my code for looping over the keys and values in one go:

```
{Object.keys(loan || {}).map((loanKey) => {
                if (loanKey === "id") return null;

                if (loan && loanKey in loan) {
                  let value: string | number | Date | null =
                    loan[loanKey as keyof typeof loan];

                  if (loanKey === "createdAt" || loanKey === "updatedAt") {
                    value = new Date(value!).toLocaleString(undefined, {
                      year: "numeric",
                      month: "long",
                      day: "numeric",
                      hour: "numeric",
                      minute: "numeric",
                    });
                  }
                  return (
                    <Card className="text-black">
                      <Flex direction={"column"} align={"center"}>
                        <Text>{formatKeyDisplay(loanKey)}: </Text>
                        <Card>{value}</Card>
                      </Flex>
                    </Card>
                  );
                }
                return null;
              })}
```

I wanted to parse the createdAt and updatedAt strings out of ISO format and into something more user-friendly, so I thought to cast the value into a Date object then use .toLocaleString() to immediately cast it back into a string.

The issue with that is that I get

```
Type 'string | Date | null' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322)
```

on trying to render `value` presumably because TypeScript doesn't like that value becomes of type `Date` even if I'm parsing it back into a string immediately.

If I try to type `value` as so :  `let value: string | number | null = loan[loanKey as keyof typeof loan];` TypeScript will just complain that

```
Type 'string | number | Date | null' is not assignable to type 'string | number | null'.
  Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string | number | null'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a separate variable for the unprocessed value and the processed value that you know won't be a `Date`:

```
let rawValue: string | number | Date | null =
  loan[loanKey as keyof typeof loan];
let value: string | number | null;

if (loanKey === "createdAt" || loanKey === "updatedAt") {
  value = new Date(rawValue!).toLocaleString(undefined, {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "long",
    day: "numeric",
    hour: "numeric",
    minute: "numeric",
  });
} else if (rawValue instanceof Date) {
  // Throw error, since the keys above are the only ones that
  // show have dates
  throw new Error(`Unexpected Date for field "${loanKey}"`);
} else {
  // This assignment should be fine, because we weeded out `Date` above
  value = rawValue;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAUBsEMGMFMAWB7SATeAnAzgKA7DJvKJPAC6ibQDuAatJAK7wBco25mAlgHYDmoAD6heTALYAjLMNAARaORIixkSAG588QtGKkKpZNF4BpeAE92nHgM24QoAMLIMuMpQBujFla59BKhLSmLKqGri43ABmoAAUkEamFqAAvGmgAESwxIrwaACC5BnCIgnGZuap6RlMAA5ouQVFAJSgAN64oKBezCQpovA08rmx1PTe8ACEzQB05MgAMsiwjPAAyn4CsUy8GFF8eQA07Z1doObwuuwZYuJY3LAZh6dd4si85IjXCQJPL6ANSyZW73R7PM6gFBMTDXEE8MH-cR8JhKWESUF-LoAX2amixoHgkGwJGicTGDF6oD4nGMCGQMQUSlaHS6DgAKohMMghlguZhjtg+AhQJ8SABrCzYUDQSTIDwkXQkUWgd6QSrveBSz6KU4ObAoIaIaDygG5PBdT5coa8QagACimD5sQABgBVG0AD1q2iUaGGSlAUWQIX2hL9GQAJG0yklzFiMs7cbh8YTiSdWWAOdwpdBsIL+Lw7h8OFD0KBpIGDsdpCsmGmaCQG3k8iqUaBnYz4M7pbL5aceixUlRaBSWHigA)

Answer (score 0):

Just define a different variable `displayValue` that contains the string you want to display, instead of reusing `value`. It can be hard for Typescript to keep up if you reassign existing variables with something of a different type.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your [problem on a sample](https://playcode.io/1805698), but I don't get the error.

```
import React from 'react';

const formatKeyDisplay = (key: string) => {
    return key.toString();
};

export default function App() {
    const loan = {
        id: 25,
        borrowerName: "Test Borrower 1",
        pipelineStage: "PROSPECT",
        loanAmount: 500000,
        transactionType: "PURCHASE",
        referralSource: "Realtor Lenny",
        borrowerEmail: "test1@gmail.com",
        propertyAddress: "1234 Test Way",
        borrowerPhone: "789-546-3142",
        purchasePrice: 700000,
        creditScore: 700,
        createdAt: "2024-03-15T21:46:18.347Z",
        updatedAt: "2024-03-15T21:46:18.347Z"
    };

    return (
        <div style={{backgroundColor: "white", width: "100%", minWidth: "500px"}}>
        {Object.keys(loan || {}).map((loanKey) => {
            if (loanKey === "id") return null;

            if (loan && loanKey in loan) {
                let value: string | number | Date | null =
                    loan[loanKey as keyof typeof loan];

                if (loanKey === "createdAt" || loanKey === "updatedAt") {
                    value = new Date(value!).toLocaleString(undefined, {
                        year: "numeric",
                        month: "long",
                        day: "numeric",
                        hour: "numeric",
                        minute: "numeric",
                    });
                }
                return (
                    <div className="text-black" key={loanKey}>
                    <div style={{display: "flex", gap: "15px", direction: "row"}}>
                        <div>{formatKeyDisplay(loanKey)}: </div>
                        <div>{value}</div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                );
            }
            return null;
        })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Could you make a sample Component, so that we can actualy see the problem?